# alternative for @modelattribute in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to have a global model object in spring. But I can't use `@modelattribute` in method level beacause I want to create that model object after some processing and using some data...What is the solution?

Comment: Your question make little to no sense at the moment and the answer you've accepted even less so. Please clarify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want, but maybe you want to use RedirectAttributes?  You can create this attribute yourself, and then pass it to another method.